# Access more than one object property in Jade Iteration

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm creating a simple iteration to loop through an array of objects in a Jade Template and add each to a select form's option elements. I need to pass the object when the form is submitted and display the name on the dropdown select field.

```
select(name= 'departure_stop', form = 'gtfsForm')
    each stop in stops
        option(value= stop) stop.stop_name
```

The above code renders in the following way. The object is successfully passed into the value field, but the stop.stop_name is passed into the DOM as a string.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add equal sign

```
option(value= stop)= stop.stop_name
```

BTW I think you don't want value to be `[object Object]` and want to use some property for `value` too.

```
option(value= stop.id)= stop.stop_name
```

Comment: Thanks Yury -- I'm new to express.